# p2p communication using winsock

Tags: c++, winsock, p2p

I am trying to achieve peer to peer communication using winsock but `gethostbyaddr` always return me NULL ,this thing works only on localhost, server_name is destination ip address

```
server_name="<--ipaddress-->"

struct sockaddr_in server;
addr = inet_addr(server_name);
cout<<"inet_addr(server_name) "<<addr<<endl;
hp = gethostbyaddr((char *)&addr, 4, AF_INET);
memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));


memcpy(&(server.sin_addr), hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
server.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
server.sin_port = htons(port);
conn_socket = socket(AF_INET, socket_type, 0); 

connect(conn_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))
```

We have already achieved p2p communication using python and it works perfectly fine on same port no and address .. thanks for any clue..

I do not have any idea how to do it in c++, in python we just used bind(---) , Can somebody show me code snippet how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting `server_name` from? Are you sure it's a valid IP address?
Also, check `WSAGetLastError()` to see specifically what's going wrong.

Remember that not all hostnames have reverse DNS entries. It's perfectly legitimate for `gethostbyaddr` to fail on a real, valid IP address. If you're doing p2p, it's best not to rely on host *names* at all, except perhaps for diagnostic displays (and fall back to IP addresses if reverse lookups fail).

**Edit**: With your new, expanded code sample, it's clear that you actually don't need `gethostbyaddr` at all.

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
memset((void*)&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_long = inet_addr(server_name);
server.sin_port = htons(port);
conn_socket = socket(AF_INET, socket_type, 0); 

connect(conn_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))
```

`gethostbyaddr` is only needed when you need the reverse DNS *name* of the server in question. `inet_addr` already gives you a suitable address to connect to.